# Add a loading spinner on HTML until it receives the required data

Tags: html, jquery, css, ajax

My Node API returns a JSON object, the object is being displayed on HTML table. However, my Node app takes some time to process and return the data. So till the time data has being retrieved I want a spinner to load on the page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table1").hide();
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#myButton").hide();
    $("#table1").show();

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8090/api/route1",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        data1: str1,
        data2: str2
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);

        console.log("Result1", res.result1);
        console.log("Result2", res.result2);
        $('#td1').append(res.result1);
        $('#td2').append(res.result2);

      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="spinner" id="loadingBtn">
  Loading...
</span>

<table class="table" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="td1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How and where do I put the spinner id so that it is only displayed until the data is fully rendered onto the HTML table.

Comment: do you mean like this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxcomplete.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table1").hide();
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#myButton").hide();
    $("#table1").show();

    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5ec78da22f0000640042721f",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);

        console.log("Result1", res.result1);
        console.log("Result2", res.result2);
        $('#td1').append(res.result1);
        $('#td2').append(res.result2);

      },
      beforeSend: function() {
         $("#loadingBtn").show();
      },
      complete: function() {
         $("#loadingBtn").hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="spinner" id="loadingBtn" style="display:none;">
  Loading...
</span>
<button id="myButton">Press</button>
<table class="table" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="td1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine, just added  $("#table1").show() and hide() as the spinner was loading along with table structure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the loading spinner on `loading` and `done`.  Show the spinner on call, and just hide it when the call is done.  like so:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res);
            }
        }).done(function() {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".spinner").fadeOut(300);
            },500);
        });
```

take a look at this codepen:
https://codepen.io/yic666kr/pen/mxmvbV

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your structure where you have it placed but I'll go with what you have put here. You have it visible when you start loading and hide it once data is loaded from your ajax.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#table1").hide();
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#myButton").hide();
    $("#table1").show();

    // show the loader when you click the button
    $('#loadingBtn').addClass('spinner--is-active')

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8090/api/route1",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        data1: str1,
        data2: str2
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);

        console.log("Result1", res.result1);
        console.log("Result2", res.result2);
        $('#td1').append(res.result1);
        $('#td2').append(res.result2);
        
        // hide the loader
        $('#loadingBtn').removeClass('spinner--is-active')
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.spinner {
  display: none;
}

.spinner--is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="spinner" id="loadingBtn">
  Loading...
</span>

<table class="table" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="td1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just show your spinner in `beforeSend` of ajax function and hide it after data is loaded under `success` function.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8090/api/route1",
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    data1: str1,
    data2: str2
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function() {
    $("#loadingBtn").show();//show spinner
  },
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);

    console.log("Result1", res.result1);
    console.log("Result2", res.result2);
    $('#td1').append(res.result1);
    $('#td2').append(res.result2);
    $("#loadingBtn").hide();//hide spinner
  }
});
```